# How to say that "not watching a movie continuously"?

Tags: verbs, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I feel awkward when I am trying to express this. Sometimes when we watch a movie on a computer, we don't watch it from the beginning to the end. In this case, is there a verb or phrase that native speakers of English uses to say something like

> I didn't watch the whole movie, I just ___ it on my computer.

Comment: *"this is the worst film I have **sat through** this year"* OR, *"I didn't **sit through**"*

Comment: Depends if you watch the whole film in chunks, or just watch some parts of the film.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Skate over/around** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skate-over-around-sth)

> To avoid dealing completely with something or to fail to pay enough attention to it.
>
> *"I didn't understand what the teacher said about prepositions, because she only skated over it."*

**Skim over** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skim)

> 3.1. Deal with or treat (a subject) briefly or superficially
>
> *"she skimmed over her meeting with Roger—it had suddenly become rather difficult to speak of him"*

Usually used in the context of reading, but can be extended to watching movies.

**Skim through** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/skim+through)

> To go through some reading material quickly or superficially
>
> *"I skimmed through the movie listings to see what was playing."*

**Cast/run one's eye over** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast/run%20one%27s%20eye%20over)

> to read or look at (something) quickly.
>
> *"Please run your eye over this and let me know what you think."*

Answer (score 1):

You might try **[skipped through](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/skip%20through)**:

> I didn't watch the whole movie, I just *skipped through* it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

**piecemeal**

> Sometimes I resort to watching movies on my phone, piecemeal. Not ideal but hey...you work with the schedule you've got.

> Here are some great movie choices to watch piecemeal on the treadmill, bike or elliptical to make 45 minutes seem like 15.

Answer (score 0):

The word *sittings* can also be used, but in a slightly different context:

> I watched the movie in multiple/several ***sittings*** instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

**in chunks**

> Let's talk about watching a movie in chunks, rather than all at once.
>
> TikTok's latest trend? Watching movies in 3-minute chunks.

I always watch movie in parts. I dont know when it began, maybe two years back. Before that I used to watch movies at one go.